# Is it possible to configure a CAN transceiver with an FDCAN microcontroller?

Tags: c++, c, stm32, can-bus, nucleo

I am trying to configure a MCP2551 CAN transceiver with my STM32 NUCLEO H7A3ZI-Q which only supports FDCAN. Is it possible to do so? If yes, what are the steps to be followed?

I have seen that FDCAN has a Classic CAN mode which is similar to the original CAN protocol, but does it use the same data frame as the original CAN or does it just tweak FDCAN data frame to mimic classic CAN and the data frame being unintelligible to the transceiver.

Comment: Trancoiver does not have anything in common with FDCAN or CAN. Electrically they are the same asd the tranciver is converting logical level CANL CANH into differential ones

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but generally CAN FD is backwards compatible in hardware. You can use CAN FD circuits either for classic ("high speed") CAN or for CAN FD, but not both at once. This goes for transceivers as well as controllers.